# How do I get this SQL statement to write to an empty excel sheet for the rows beyond the first one?

Tags: sql, excel, oledb

I am attempting to send some data, stored as local variables in an automation tool, to an Excel sheet using OleDB 12. So far, my code (below) is what I've come up with that works to write data successfully to the first line of a templated Excel sheet (headers are already filled out). My problem is every subsequent iteration is not writing data to any line after the first successful (Index 2).

I've tried changing the where clause to work with line index rather than finding empty rows, but that was unsuccessful and returned errors. I've also tried to leverage the 'INSERT INTO' statement, which is also was returning perplexing run-time errors every which way I try to write the statement. Can you not use 'INSERT' with Oledb?

Update statement (semi-successful):

```
UPDATE [Sheet1$] 
SET [SAP_ID] = %SapEmployeeNumber%
WHERE [SAP_ID] IS NULL;
```

Insert statement (have not gotten to work):

```
INSERT INTO Sheet1$ (SAP_ID)
VALUES %SapEmployeeNumber%
WHERE [SAP_ID] IS NULL
```

The expectation is to write data to the first empty row (In other words, the employee number is blank).

Comment: So what *is* happening? Is it throwing an error after the first row, or just writing and overwriting that row?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Nothing is happening; there's no error nor any data adaptation.

Comment: Nothing is happening? So, when you run your code, it just...runs, does nothing, finishes?

Comment: That's correct. No updates are made to the excel sheet. The existing data is unaffected. However, keep in mind, this is only after the first try, which I am able to write data. It's only after that first iteration that nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Well, that's not nothing happening then, is it? Data is being written on the first pass, then *not* being written on subsequent iterations.

Comment: Are you here to help? Or are you here to critique my written English? Please take this positively. I appreciate your willingness to respond, but the intent of your responses appear mostly ambiguous to me. I'd like to progress on the issue at hand. Therefore, if you have insight on that particularly, then I'm all ears and open to suggestions.

Comment: The issue here is clarity: "doesn't work" gives me no information to work with, and is very hard to reproduce. Per the community guidelines, you should be posting enough code that we can paste it into an IDE so that *we* can replicate the problem, solve the problem, then help you solve the problem. I'm asking questions to get you to be *specific* about what's wrong, so I/others can actually help.

Comment: Also, for your inserts, I suspect a Select-into statement will move things forward for you. That lets you include a where clause and a target.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: an `INSERT` statement **NEVER** has a `WHERE` clause - [check the official MS docs on `INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql).

Secondly: you need to put the values in the `VALUES` section into parentheses, like this:

```
INSERT INTO Sheet1$ (SAP_ID)
VALUES (%SapEmployeeNumber%)
```

Comment: Ah! good to know, thanks. I went ahead and wrapped the variable in the braces. Unfortunately, I am still seeing this error: "Runtime Error: Error in SQL Statement: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement."

Comment: terminology note: [ ] braces or brackets { } curly braces/brackets ( ) *parentheses*